# What's the point of a foreground service to record audio in Android 11?

Tags: android, audio, service

On one of my apps activities a user can start an `AudioSession`. This `AudioSession` runs until the user explicitly stops it in the app, or the app is terminated. During an `AudioSession`, [AudioRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) and [AudioTrack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack) are used to record and play audio. Recording and playing should continue even if my app is minimized or the screen goes off.

As far as I understand I want to record audio in background. There are several restrictions on this in different Android versions (correct me if I'm wrong):

- In the past recording audio was possible in any kind of service
- Starting Android 9 audio recording can no longer happen in a service other than a foreground service:

> One more change was added in Android 9: only apps running in the foreground (or a foreground service) could capture the audio input. [1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/sharing-audio-input#pre-behavior)

- Starting Android 11, the behaviour does not make sense at all, as explained below.

So below is an exceed of the [official Foreground services documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types), omissions are marked with [...].

> ### Declare foreground service types
>
> [...]
>
> If your app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and accesses the camera or microphone in a foreground service, declare the camera or microphone foreground service types, respectively, as attributes of your  component.
>
> Note: Although adding a foreground service type gives a foreground service the capability to access location, the camera, or the microphone, this foreground service is still affected by the access restrictions that were introduced in Android 11.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Restricted access to location, camera, and microphone
>
> To help protect user privacy, Android 11 (API level 30) introduces limitations to when a foreground service can access the device's location, camera, or microphone. The limitations depend on the app's state when the service starts.
>
> #### Restrictions applied to services that start while an app is running in the background
>
> On Android 11 and higher, if your app starts a foreground service while the app is running in the background, the service has the following access restrictions:
>
> [...]
>
> - The service cannot access the microphone or camera.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Restrictions applied to services that start while an app is running in the foreground
>
> If your app starts a foreground service while the app is running in the foreground ("while-in-use"), the service has the following access restrictions:
>
> [...]
>
> - If the user has granted the RECORD_AUDIO permission to your app, the service can access the microphone only while the app is running in the foreground.

To conclude the above: If my foreground service is started while my app is in background, I can not record audio. If my foreground service is started while my app is foreground ("while-in-use"), I can only record audio while my app is foreground ("while-in-use").

So now my question is: Why would I use a foreground service if it has literally no influence on audio recording on Android 11+? I can just record audio, without a foreground service in my app to achieve exactly the same behaviour as with a foreground service. What am I missing?

Comment: hi hope this will help
For your foreground service in manifest u should define the type : 
 *** <service ... android:foregroundServiceType="location|camera" />
and in your service when starting your foreground service 
*** if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) startForeground(notificationID, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_....)
        else startForeground(notificationID, notification)
the type can be : 
FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_(LOCATION|CAMERA|MICROPHONE)
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `android:foregroundServiceType="microphone"` is set in the foreground service declaration, you can record audio while non activity is in foreground but only the foreground service is active. I did a quick test to confirm this behavior for Android 13 device with app targeting sdk 31.

I think if your app has an active foreground service it is considered running in the foreground and the restriction do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Exemptions from the restrictions
>
> In some situations, even if a foreground service is started while the app is running in the background, it can still access location, camera, and microphone information while the app is running in the foreground ("while-in-use"). In these same situations, if the service declares a foreground service type of location and is started by an app that has the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, this service can access location information all the time, even when the app is running in the background.

> ###### The following list contains these situations:
>
> 1. The service is started by a system component.
> 2. The service is started by interacting with app widgets.
> 3. The service is started by interacting with a notification.
> 4. The service is started as a PendingIntent that is sent from a different, visible app.
> 5. The service is started by an app that is a device policy controller that is running in device owner mode.
> 6. The service is started by an app which provides the VoiceInteractionService.
> 7. The service is started by an app that has the START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND privileged permission.

I'm trying 3. but unsuccessfully. How did you get on?

Comment: Please show some code or give more details of your attempts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266891/how-do-i-access-the-microphone-if-the-foreground-service-is-running-while-the-ap

Answer (score -2):

Audio in background with foreground service
first in manifest on service declaration

```
<service ... android:foregroundServiceType="microphone" />
```

---

second in service class when starting your foreground service

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) startForeground(notificationID, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE)
else startForeground(notificationID, notification)
```

for more info see
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types